# Angular 8 ngrx store how to get reducer value without subscribe callback?

Tags: angular, angular8, ngrx-store

I am new to the angular and rx.

I see a lot of examples just use code something like this.

```
this.store.select('city')
this.store.pipe(select(action()))
```

However, those code just returning _Store instance.

The correct way to get value from reducer is that

```
this.store.pipe(select(action())).subscribe(val => this.val)
```

Is there any way I can just get value from reducer without callback or subscribe?

Something like generator in redux saga ??

```
const city = yield select(state => state.city)
```

Comment: Depends on the use case. If you want to use a value in an effect for example you could use withLatestFrom. Maybe tell us more where and when do you want to use the value?

Comment: since whole angular thing is async/reactive and effects (where you also can use current store values) are also reactive, i have a hard time seeing where would you ever need explicit store value imperatively? can you describe a usecase? ps. you could take a look at `withLatestFrom` operator which is usually used in effects to get current value of state in order to compute a new one (or use in services) but feels like its not directly what you want.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm and dee zg when the redux store update I need to build url and fetch some data from endpoint. I do not need store value imperatively. but just dont want to have callback hell.

Comment: where do you do that? in effects? or some component?

Comment: @deezg I add that in onInit and that dispatch to run effect

Comment: ok, so is there a reason why you couldnt use `withLatestFrom` in that effect that handles action you dispatch? maybe i am missing something but thats very common pattern.

Comment: I did not even know withLatestFrom exist. I will try thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you just need a value in a html template, I suggest not subscribing, but referencing this observable directly in the template together with an `async` pipe.

```
//typescript
public value$ = this.store.pipe(select(...));
```

```
//html
{{ value$ | async }}
```

If you need a value of the stream in the TS code and you want to unsubscribe from the observable just after accessing the value (you dont want to call callback whenever new value is emmited), you can use operator `take(1)`:

```
this.store.pipe(select(...)).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a wrapper (that I wrote) around ngrx/store, and it allows such an operation using code like this:

```
store('city').state(); // returns the current value of `city`
```

Or, equivalently (and more recommended according to its style guide):

```
store.state().city;
```

The wrapper is [`ng-app-state`](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/ng-app-state). It is a shift in thinking from the traditional action/reducer patterns of ngrx, but one that has worked well for me.